# Problem with Azure SDK 1.3 Tracing

Tags: azure

I'm having an apparent AppDomain issue with tracing from within web pages (as opposed to the WebRole).  Basically, if I invoke one of the tracing methods (i.e. Trace.TraceWarning("Ooops!")) the trace message doesn't show up in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator.  The message does, however, show up just fine  in the Output window.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that for now this is just a limitation of the Compute Emulator... it only shows trace messages from your RoleEntryPoint code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Now that I think about it your suggestion makes perfect sense....

Comment: I ended up creating my own TraceListener then instantiating it twice; once for the WebRole AppDomain and once for the the website AppDomain (through Global.asax)